# C# How to add a splash screen to an Excel VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I am new to writing C#. I have created an Excel VSTSO addin. I would like to create a splash screen showing the progress of my code at different points. I have searched the web and can't see any code examples of a splash screen for an Excel VSTO addin. I have seen this question on stack overflow: [VSTO splash screen or progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555256/vsto-splash-screen-or-progress-bar) but the link in the question that would show a code example is broken. I've also seen reference on this site to the backgroundworker and progress bar but I'd rather use a splash screen. Can anyone advise an example of how this would be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a pretty straightforward task for Office add-ins. You can display a child window with a progress bar (spinning circle or whatever progress indicator you wish to use for that). To display a child window and prevent the focus from trapping to the main window you need to set the parent window handle for your newly created window with a progress indicator. For that you need to create an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.iwin32window?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) interface which represents your parent window (Office application) and which can be passed to the form constructor. Here is how it might look like:

```
public class Win32Window : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public Win32Window(int windowHandle)
    {
        _windowHandle = new IntPtr(windowHandle);
    }

    IntPtr _windowHandle;

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _windowHandle; }
    }
}
```

The `Win32Window` class can be used in the following way:

```
// initialize form
var frm = new Form();
frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
frm.MinimizeBox = false;
frm.MaximizeBox = false;
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;   

// create the native window handle
var nw = new Win32Window(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);

// show with owner
frm.Show(nw);
```

All just you need now is to add a progress indicator!

Comment: Thank you that's great. So you are creating a form which the win32window sits in? I looked at the link you provided but I don't understand what the win32window is. And where you would put the progress indicator. Thank you.

Comment: An instance of your custom form with a progress indicator is created on the first line of code.

Comment: Thank you. And then once my code has compiled I just close the form. Sorry new to this.

Comment: Yes, use the `form.close` method for that.

Comment: Thanks again thats very helpful. You create the form in code, can one design one and call that up, or is that not possible?

Comment: You can design the form as you need it. I just illustrated how the form instance can be created and configured at runtime programmatically.

Comment: Last question, the examples I have seen online are with a winform and a button is pressed and a splash screen is created while whatever code is compiling. What's the main difference when doing this in a excel vsto addin?

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions in new threads so other SO users could recognize questions and answers easily. Too much information in the single thread.

Comment: In your first comment under your answer you said '...progress indicator is created on the first line of code.' In the last line of your answer you put 'All just you need now is to add a progress indicator!'. I don't understand what this means can you explain please? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I mean an instance of the progress indicator form on the first line of code.

Comment: Thank you. It works well thank you. Putting a progress bar inside I feel is quite tricky for me. I tried it with a background worker, but my code form the addin I don't now how I would reference that into the _DoWork event. I think I would be quite happy with just the marquee progress bar that would not need to be related to the progress % of my code, its more just as a visual.